# Creating a class library project template and changing the default class' name

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, class-library, project-template

I'm trying to create one simple project template for visual studio. The project is of type class library. When creating a new project from that template I wish to get the user's desired project name and use that same name for the default class in the class lib. project.
Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible by implementing a Wizard that shows UI and provides additional configuration data to the template expansion.

[Full documentation is available on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx).